# Oracle APEX - how to mark a classic report row as selected

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I have a classic report where the rows are displayed in form of cards. I need to mark one card as selected whenever the report is loaded, perhaps by changing background color of that card. 
The report is based on one SQL query and selected card should be based on querying another table. If a different card is selected I want the database to be updated to that selection.

How can this be done? I'd appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

I gave the region a static id but do not see how I can access individual rows - cards in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you are using the Universal Theme's "Cards" report template.  That can handle highlighting via icons or colors.  I have set up an example based on the EMP table [here on apex.oracle.com](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=139981:6) (login as demo/demo).

[image]

My query:

```
select
  ename card_title,
  ename card_subtitle,
  job card_text,
  hiredate card_subtext,
  '' card_modifiers,
  apex_page.get_url(p_items=>'P6_EMPNO',p_values=>empno) card_link,
  case when empno = :P6_EMPNO then 'u-color-39' else 'u-color-29' end card_color,
  case when empno = :P6_EMPNO then 'fa-check' end card_icon,
  '' card_initials
from emp
```

I have a hidden page item called P6_EMPNO, and when the user clicks on one of the cards that gets set by this link:

```
  apex_page.get_url(p_items=>'P6_EMPNO',p_values=>empno) card_link,
```

Then that is used to specify an icon and different color for the card via these:

```
  case when empno = :P6_EMPNO then 'u-color-39' else 'u-color-29' end card_color,
  case when empno = :P6_EMPNO then 'fa-check' end card_icon,
```

You can find out all about Universal Theme cards, colors etc. at https://apex.oracle.com/ut/

Comment: Thanks! So in this case apex_page.get_url is used to set a page variable?

Comment: I tried that and now whenever I click on a card, the page gets refreshed and I am taken to a different tab (this region is on one of the many tabs on the page). How can I prevent it from going anywhere? Also can I add a dynamic action to this?

Comment: ok, I fixed the page refresh issue by setting p_request parameter of get_url. Now all I have left is figuring out how to call a dynamic action

Comment: Call a dynamic action when?

Comment: when a card is clicked or selected

Comment: I also noticed that when `empno = :P6_EMPNO` the color is changed only when I mouse over the card. How can I change it so that it shows up when region is loaded, not when I mouse over the card

Comment: I don't know about the color - accortding to https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=42:3100:::NO::: it is a matter od setting Style=Block in the template options, but that doesn't seem to be an option (perhaps it is coming in APEX 18)

Comment: The cards are `<li>` tags with a class of `t-Cards-item` so you could use that as a jQuery selector in your DA to fire when a card is clicked.  To identify which card was clicked you really need them to have an ID, which they don't unfortunately. However, you can add one by copying the Cards template and adding `id="#CARD_ID#"`in the `<li>` tag then selecting e.g. `empno as card_id` in the report.